# Unable to crop the retinal image

Tags: python, opencv

I  am trying to crop the retinal image using canny detection and by finding countours using opencv. I am using the below code but I am not getting the cropped image instead I am getting image like

[image: retinal_image_cropped.jpg].

**What is problem with the following code.**.

**Original Image is like this**

[image: original_retinal_image.jpg]

```
import cv2
# Load image, convert to grayscale, and find edges
image = cv2.imread('IDRiD_001.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 120, 255, 1)

# Find contour and sort by contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Find bounding box and extract ROI
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    break

cv2.imwrite('retinal_image.jpg',ROI)
```

Comment: can you please add the original image as well?

Answer (score 1):

That is because there ROI is assigned the bounding box of the last contour in the cnts list. Either define ROI outside the for loop and take the union of the ROI's using the union operator |, or somehow make sure that there is only one contour.

```
top = []
left = []
bot = []
right = []
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    top.append(y)
    bot.append(y+h)
    left.append(x)
    right.append(x+w)

t, l, b, r = (min(top), min(left), max(bot), max(right))
ROI = image[t:b, l:r]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code. As I am new to open cv.

Comment: something like this

Comment: Thank you very much